# Vite.js still using boiler part templates even after modification?

Tags: javascript, frontend, vite

Trying to create my first vite.js app. after initializing the project and installing the dependencies i  edited index.html to show a normal hello world, other files i left them empty.

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="favicon.svg" /> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Hello Wolrd</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"> 
      <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
      <h1>Hello Wolrd</h1>
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

However i edit index.html style.css or main.js , the localhost just keep showing the welcome page from vite.js, so i inspected the page and it looks like it still using the boiler-path template:

[image]

`EDIT:`

someone commented that main.js is the entry point of vite.js i edited too to show a simple hello world to no brainer...

```
import './style.css'

document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = `
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
`
```

This is my files hierarchy:

[image]

if you need any more info let me know?

`EDIT 2:`

I was using MacOs mojave version 10.14.6
I changed to another Imac with the same os and version and it worked ...

Answer (score 1):

In `main.js` you will see:

```
document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = `
  <h1>Hello Vite!</h1>
  <a href="https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html" target="_blank">Documentation</a>
`
```

Which replaces all which is in `<div id="app"></div>`

With

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello Vite!</h1>
  <a href="https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html" target="_blank">Documentation</a>
</div>
```

Vite bundler is placing/fixing the `<script>` at the end before body because its in the wrong place.

---

If you want `Hello World!` then you should change the content in `main.js`

```
document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = `
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
`
```

Comment: yes the last snippet of the code is what i've done  exactly and i placed the script tag in the head tag in index.html too however it still loading the initial boiler path.

Comment: works for me, maybe your saving the wrong file: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-q8798d?file=main.js&terminal=dev

Comment: surely im not , check out my files hierarchy above.

Comment: @home, are you sure you haven't stopped the dev server? Try restarting it. (e.g: stop the serve, even if it looks active and start it again). Another possible cause: you haven't actually saved the changes. HMR only picks up changes when you save the file, not when you type in it.

Comment: yes try that too, i inspected the resources again and it surely uses the older boiler-parts for index.html main.js and style.css, https://ibb.co/z4ZB42M

Comment: try clearing your browser cache or Ctrl+5